# Area between a circle and an spiral.

Tags: area, polar-coordinates

I have to evaluate the following area:

[image]

Since the area of the circle is $16\pi$, I thought about evaluate the area of the spiral from $0$ to $4$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4}\theta^2 d\theta=\frac{32}{3}$$
because the curves have intersection when $r=\theta=4$. And since the area of the 4th quadrant is $4\pi$ then, my final answer is
$$16\pi-\frac{32}{3}-4\pi=12\pi-\frac{32}{3}$$

I'd lke to know if it's correct.

Comment: Not correct. You still have some part of the circle you mistakenly consider in the third quadrant.

Comment: You should subtract the area of the circle up to the point of intersection, not merely the last quadrant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back to basics: The area in polar coordinates is given by

$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int r^2d\theta 
$$

So, here we have

$$
\begin{align}
A&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4 (r^2-\theta^2)d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[r^2\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3} \bigg]_0^4\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[4^3-\frac{4^3}{3} \bigg]\\
&=\frac{64}{3}\approx 21.3333
\end{align}
$$

I've verified this result numerically in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from the area under a cycloid

> Consider the non-self-intersecting plane curve defined by the parametric equations
> $$x=(t), y=y(t), a\leq t \leq b$$
> assume $x(t)$ differentiable, the area between the curve and $x$-axis is
> $$A = \int_a^by(t)x'(t)dt$$

---

Your spiral has parametric equation
$$\gamma(t) = (t\cos (t), t\sin(t)), \ t\in [0,4] $$
And you can divide in three section

1. The area between $y$-axis and curve from $0$ to $\pi/2$ (this interval is on the $y$-axis)
2. Area between curve and $x$-axis from $0$ to $-\pi$
3. Last part, area between the curve and $y$-axis from $0$ to $4\sin(4)$

With the formula above you should be able to evaluate the portions mentioned. I honestly tried to evaluate only the part first part (using the formula with respect to $y$-axis)
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x(t)y'(t)dt =\int_0^{\pi/2}\big(t\cos(t)\sin(t) + t^2 \cos^2(t)\big)dt= \pi^3/48 $$
I think is not that bad, maybe this isn't the most efficient way. Hope this helps!